# Most effective way to get number of items with similar value in a Django Query

Tags: django, performance

I am looking for the fastest way to compute the following:

Given a Contact model like this:

```
class Contact(basemodel):

    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, )
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, )
```

I am looking for the fastest query to get a list of sender for a specific item with the number of contact objects they have for this scenario.

I would get the list of senders like this
senders = Contact.objects.filter(item=self.item).values_list('sender', flat=True)

but I would then need to count number of time each sender is in the list.

I am sure there's a cleaner faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if your model has two fields with the same relationship you must send a backwards name which is the related_name, like this:

```
class Contact(basemodel):

    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='recipient_contact' )
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='sender_contact' )
```

After that to retrive a list of senders you can do the Query in the actually sender(User), and just annotate the count:

```
User.objects.filter(sender_contact__item=self.item).annotate(count=Count('sender_contact'))
```

I guess this will work! let me know anything!

Comment: thans for the backwards name, I had try to skip as much as possible editing the actual code.